# Mern Stack AWS s3

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, amazon-s3, mern

Hi I'm looking to implement aws s3 storage bucket for images for a mern project that a user can upload and set as profile picture and create posts with images, my question how do I go about doing this on the the back end I want the user to be able to make all the crud operations, this will be my first time using aws so any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

While you could have your React front-end interact with S3 directly using something like S3 pre-signed URLs (1), it may be difficult to get the CRUD functionality you want in your front-end.

A set of AWS lambda functions for the CRUD operations would be the best approach if your backend architecture is serverless. Otherwise, your nodejs backend can manage S3 get/update/delete functions for your front-end.

References:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

Comment: hi thanks for the reply i have set up a bucket with aws and stored images in the bucket my question is how to create a link between my mongoDB and AWS S3 so when a user creates a post or uploads an image,  i have 2 schema models, i am making a ref to the user inside my post Schema so user retrieve his images related to the post how can i insert or create this collection in mongodb atlas and also have a ref to the user that i can call in my front end

Comment: USER SCHEMA

`const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true },
  fullname: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);`

Comment: IMAGE SCHEMA

`const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const imageSchema = new Schema(
  {
    image: {
      type: "String",
      default: "",
      required: true,
    },
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("PostImage", imageSchema);`